# python raw_input def input problem

Tags: python, input

I am only going to post the portion where the problem is at, the program has no error (all the codes are valid except for this `raw_input` problem)

I tested with `search_function(1)` and etc and it worked.

But if I do this while loop, it doesn't print anything. 
Example output:

> Enter a number to print specific table,
>   or STOP to quit: 2 Enter a number to
>   print specific table, or STOP to quit:
>   2 Enter a number to print specific
>   table, or STOP to quit: 1 Enter a
>   number to print specific table, or STOP
>   to quit:  Enter a number to print
>   specific table, or STOP to quit: 1
>   Enter a number to print specific table,
>   or STOP to quit:  Enter a number to
>   print specific table, or STOP to quit:
>   STOP

```
def search_function(x):
    if x == 1:
        for student in students:
            print "%-17s|%-10s|%-6s|%3s" % student.print_information()
        print '\n'

    if x == 2:
        print "%-17s|%-10s|%s" %(header[0],header[1],header[4])
        print "-" * 45
        for student in students:
            print "%-17s|%-10s|%s" %student.print_first()
        print '\n'
        print "Simple Analysis on favorite sports: "
        # Printing all sports that are specified by students
        for s in set(Student.sports): # class attribute
            print s, Student.sports.count(s), round(((float(Student.sports.count(s)) / num_students) *100),1)

        # Printing sports that are not picked 
        allsports = ['Basketball','Football','Other','Baseball','Handball','Soccer','Volleyball','I do not like sport']
        for s in set(allsports) - set(Student.sports):
            print s, 0, '0%'
        choice_list = Student.sports
        for choice in choice_list:
            choice_dict[choice] = choice_dict.get(choice, 0) + 1
        print max(choice_dict)
        print min(choice_dict)

    elif x == 3:
        print "%-17|%-10s|%-16s|%s" %(header[0],header[1],header[5],header[6])
        print "-" * 45
        for student in students:
            print "%-17s|%-10s|%-16s|%s" % student.print_second()
        print '\n'

    elif x == 4:
        print "%-17s|%-10s|%s" %(header[0],header[1],header[7])
        print "-" * 45
        for student in students:
            print "%-17s|%-10s|%s" %student.print_third()
        print '\n'

    elif x == 5:
        print "%-17s|%-10s|%-15s|%s" %(header[0],header[1],header[8],header[9])
        print "-" * 45
        for student in students:
            print "%-17s|%-10s|%-16s|%s" % student.print_fourth()
        print '\n'

x = raw_input("Enter a number to print specific table, or STOP to quit: ")
while x != 'STOP':
    search_function(x)
    x = raw_input("Enter a number to print specific table, or STOP to quit: ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test for `x == 'STOP'` first and `break` if True, else cast to int and call `search_function`:

```
while True:
    x = raw_input("Enter a number to print specific table, or STOP to quit: ")
    if x == 'STOP':
        break
    search_function(int(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

`raw_input()` returns string, while your code expects integer. Use `search_function(int(x))` or change conditions to compare with strings.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. However, one reason to use raw is to recognize the input STOP, but because it is int, it simply returns an error. It is fine for my purpose but just want to know, is there any alternative to this?
I can create an extra if/else statement, but please int, will just return error before it hits my false statement

Comment: Yes, there is alternative (quoting): "or change conditions to compare with strings", i.e. change `x == 1` to `x == '1'` etc. But passing `int` into `search_function()` won't cause an error, since comparisson  with `'STOP'` is outside function.